# PHP mejorar una función con if

Tags: php, array, funciones, recursión

mi pregunta es la siguiente, deseo aprender a como agregar a un loop o a una funcion recursiva parametros avanzados como en el ejemplo siguiente:

Tengo varios if lo cual no es lo que busco pues los valores de $NumeroCaracteristicas son variables y pueden cambiar y solo se puede para 3 niveles, la idea es una función o loop que me permita agregar a la función get_array_path los valores dependiendo de la cantidad de $NumeroCaracteristicas,

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $NumeroCaracteristicas - 1; $i++) {
        if ($i === 0) {
            $arrTextTemp[0] = get_array_path([], $output, false);
            $PrimerItem = current($arrTextTemp[0]);
        }
        if ($i === 1) {
            $arrTextTemp[1] = get_array_path([$PrimerItem], $output, false);
            sort($arrTextTemp[1]);
            $SegundoItem = current($arrTextTemp[1]);
        }
        if ($i === 2) {
            $arrTextTemp[2] = get_array_path([$PrimerItem, $SegundoItem], $output, false);
            sort($arrTextTemp[2]);
            //Y asi continuua cada if
        }
    }
```

Existe una posibilidad de hacerlo que no tenga que poner un if? puesto que necesito esa estructura para la función get_array_path

Mil gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Al parecer bastarián dos cosas: 1. Si a cada paso agregas un elemento a $arrTextTemp que es devuelto por la función get_array_path(), se podría escribir: `$arrTextTemp = []; $arrTextTemp[] = get_array_path($arrTextTemp, $output, false);` y 2. eliminar los if. Pero no veo claro el papel de sort() y si se está o no aplicando correctamente. Debes mostrar algo más de código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eliminar los if de tu código debes declarar algunas variables auxiliares que almacenen en cada loop del for (o de un while inclusive) los valores que quieres recoger.

El codigo propuesto es el siguiente:

```
$arrTextTemp = array();
$arrInputItems = array();

for ($i = 0; $i <= $NumeroCaracteristicas - 1; $i++) {
    
    $arrTextTemp[$i] = get_array_path($arrInputItems, $output, false); //Supongo que la funcion retorna algun array procesado
    sort($arrTextTemp[$i]); //se ordena el array
    $arrInputItems[] = current($arrTextTemp[$i]); //obtengo el valor y agrego al array
}
```

Seria interesante saber que es lo que retorna la funcion get_array_path, para evaluar el correcto uso de sort y current.

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda. :)

Comment: Excelente Ricardo, me has ayudado mucho, mil gracias por explicarme